# Cannot reopen Vertex Workbench Notebook after Saving from Local VSCode

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I've created a User-Managed Notebook for Vertex AI and have connected to the compute instance via IAP on my local machine. I'm able to successfully open the Jupyter Notebooks saved on the Workbench instance and execute their code in my local VSCode without issue. However, when I save the Notebook and try to reopen it in JupyterLab in Vertex on my browser, I receive an error:

```
File Load Error for [FILE_NAME]
Unhandled error
```

I can tell that the files are successfully being saved back to the instance based on their Modified: [DATETIME] stamp but I cannot open them.

Comment: Files in User Managed Notebooks are stored by default under /home/jupyter/ folder. Which permissions (owner/group) do you see for: 1) Files created in VScode, 2) Files created in JupyterLab UI. You can use Jupyter Terminal